# Specify jest test files directory

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I wanted only to test files located in a specific directory only.

How do I specify that I want tests to run to files only on a specific directory and ignore others?

I have installed jest via npm

```
  "jest": "^23.6.0",
```

and specified my test command in package.json via

```
scripts:{
    "test": "jest --verbose"
 }
```

The above runs all the files but I want it to run for files in a specific directory e.g. latest directory only.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Add the directory name as an argument

```
scripts:{
    "test": "jest --verbose ./my-directory"
}
```

Comment: Just to help other jest juniors like me, all your tests files must end int '.test.js' or jest will not find them.

Comment: This will also include any subdirectories with the name `my-directory`.

Answer (score 57):

Add configuration to your package.json.

```
"jest": {
  "testMatch": ["**/laratest/**/*.test.js"]
}
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testmatch-arraystring

Comment: This can be used for scripts as well: `"test:unit": "jest --testMatch '**/src/test/**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)'"` (I wasn't aware of that).

Comment: Yeah it's 2023, this answer is out of date

Answer (score 23):

Inside `./jest.config.js` you can add an array of directories to search

```json
// A list of paths to directories that Jest should use to search for files in
roots: [
    "./",
    "../more-files/"
],
```

Comment: This is what I needed, the configuration snippet to be added to `jest.config.js`
If want to you post this as an answer to a question specifically on config for `jest.config.js` I'll post a question and send it to you.

Comment: Yes, it gives you more control over location. Sure.

Answer (score 9):

This article

https://bambielli.com/til/2018-09-09-moving-jest-config-out-of-root/

suggests doing something like this in your config.js file, and I quote the article:

```
// jest.conf from inside `config/` directory
{
  rootDir: '../',
  globalSetup: {...},
}
```

Answer (score 8):

[edit: as noted in other answers, the root tests directory can be an argument (e.g. `jest ... laratest`), as of the original writing, this didn't work]

Add the `--rootdir` option to your command:

`jest --verbose --rootDir=laratest`

Or in scripts:

```
scripts:{
    "test": "jest --verbose --rootDir=laratest"
 }
```

As noted by @Dimitri, this will treat laratest as the location for configuration, not just tests.  For that case, just add the argument.

Comment: Not so good to recommend unless you want to move your configuration in laratest

Answer (score 1):

You must be specific in order to avoid running other directories with the same name. For example, this runs only the test in `clients`:

```
yarn jest "$PWD/clients"
```

but this runs tests in any folder named `clients`:

```
yarn jest clients
# also: yarn jest ./clients
```

Answer (score 0):

// In jest.config.js set the rootDir

```
module.exports = {
 //other configs..
 rootDir:"./src"
};
```